# Amazon S3 Bucket static files not accessible from my Heroku-hosted Django app

Tags: django, amazon-s3, heroku

Django app hosted on Heroku. All static files are in an AWS S3 bucket with "Block all public access: Off", ACL set to "allow list/read" across the board, and the "access: public" tag is displayed under permissions. Launching Django app from Heroku dashboard is met with Bad request 400 error. Launching with debug=True shows more:

"SuspiciousOperation at /
Attempted access to '/img/faviconB-32x32.png' denied."

Removing the link tag for that exact resource in my index.html is no improvement, same error occurs for any remaining static files.

I can access any item in the bucket with its object url without issue, for example: https://heroku-brainteasers-app-tmurphy.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/static/img/brainteaserslogo.jpg

my django settings.py:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'heroku-brainteasers-app-tmurphy'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None  # Use S3 bucket's setting

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'mydjangosite.storage_backends.StaticStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'mydjangosite.storage_backends.PublicMediaStorage'

STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/static/'
MEDIA_URL = f"https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/media/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
]
```

Heroku log shows this, where path appears to be empty?:

```
2023-05-27T19:51:09.437549+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=brainteasers.herokuapp.com request_id=923235e3-17ea-4615-a0b8-6f49e5a0b06b fwd="66.31.89.108" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=333ms status=400 bytes=447 protocol=https
```

If I remove all the static file 's from my html, taking the bucket out of the loop entirely, the app loads and I see the home page. It seems like the django settings are failing to request the resources properly from my bucket, since the bucket is clearly labeled "public".